# Set Authorization Token in request header of GET route in django

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I'm trying to access the below URL using HTTPResponseRedirect which is protected by Django_restframework_simplejwt. I would like to redirect to below URL after the signup success, for the email and mobile verification.

> http://base_url/acc_verification

Assuming, I do have an access token, Now, How do I set the Authorization token in the request header to load the above page.

> Authorization: Token

Python - 3.6.8
Django - 2.2.3
djangorestframework_simplejwt - Latest

Comment: what is your frontend framework?
you can redirect with your framework's router after successful registration

Comment: bootstrap+Javascri+Django

Comment: you can use jQuery's [beforeSend](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) callback to add an HTTP header with the authentication information
if that's not helpful 
please add the javascript/front-end codes you're trying to work with